# 301 Redirect without hosting & DNS

Tags: redirection, web-hosting

I have an old website, let's call it "olddomain.com". I have an existing new website, let's call it "newdomain.com". As the old website is to be discontinued, so What I want to do is to make "olddomain" links redirect to newdomain.com links. For example "olddomain.com/link1" is to be redirected to "newdomain.com/newlink" What will be the best method to redirect? For now, I have the old website live, but after 6 months, old website hosting will not be available? or I should keep hosting for the old website. The old website is on "Rebel.ca", so no DNS is available.

Comment: Are you really changing the domain name and the path? i.e. oldomain.com/link1 = newdomain.com/newlink. This makes it nearly impossible to do any redirection. You'd have to redirect every link individually to whatever new link you created on the new server. If you kept all the paths the same, i.e. oldomain.com/link1 = newdomain.com/link1 then it would be a simple redirect. However, I don't understand why you are getting rid of the domain. Keep both domains and host them on the same server linked to the same website, so both old and new work.

Comment: Thank you, Appeleoddity, actually old domain is an insurance company, which is acquired by the main insurance company. However, links on the old domain are only 10-12. Thanks